# Display acf taxonomy attachment the_content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

On wordpress, using ACF I've added a taxonomy field to the attachment to all images. I now want to display the taxonomy field in the html 'id="the-taxonomy">'. My main goal is using it as an anchor. So you'd go to my website - Fakewebsite.com/work/toast#the-taxonomy.

I cannot seem to display the taxonomy tag in the html. At the moment it is just displaying the first random tag. (apples)

The html looks like this - https://paste.pics/98d4ab6b52b0951c31df62b54534b1b7 and the attachment looks like this: https://paste.pics/06d35483028b09520dc3d822d10d06e5 At the moment it says id="Apples" I want it to say "business card"

Id appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content','new_content');
function new_content($content) {

    $term = get_queried_object();
    $test = get_field('tag_cat_acf', get_post_thumbnail_id());

    {

        $content = str_replace('<img ', '<img data-attr="'.  $test->name .'" ', $content);
        return $content;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you getting the term?

Comment: I'm not quite sure which image holds this field. You are using `get_post_thumbnail_id()` but I don't think that gets run through `the_content` unless your theme is doing that, although I could be wrong on that part.

Comment: @HowardE Hi, what should I be getting? Sorry I'm new to php development. Thank you

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hi, do you have any suggestions? I've tried so many combinations, and this combination seems to be the only one that actually displays something (I'm new to php development). Thank you

Comment: I shoud ask... Why are you getting the queried object? What is the purpose of get post thumbnail id? Is the ACF field related to a taxonomy, a post, or the media item?

Comment: @HowardE Hi, the ACF field is a taxonomy attachment to all images. It appears here: https://paste.pics/06d35483028b09520dc3d822d10d06e5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're looking for, and I think your approach isn't quite the way I would go.

I used this filter `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`. Which allows you to add attributes to media items.  Then you can use this filter to get the media item id, and retrieve the ACF field.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'dd_custom_attribute_acf', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Filter the media item to add an ACF data-attribute to an image.
 *
 * @param array  $attr - The media item attributes.
 * @param object $attachment - The media item post object.
 * @return array
 */
function dd_custom_attribute_acf( $attr, $attachment ) {
    // get_field of whatever your field name is here.  
    $attr['data-attr'] = get_field( 'tag_cat_acf', $attachment->ID );
    return $attr;
}
```

I added this to my functions.php and it did add the contents of my custom field to the image html.

Comment: Thank you so much Howard. I appreciate your help so much